# Getting asp.net c# code to run as Windows Authenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to have the c# code for my asp website to run as the user who is authenticated through windows authentication?

After spending a bit of time researching I understand I would need impersonation, but when I configure impersonation for example like this: `<identity impersonate="true" />` I get an error from IIS about how the web config is setup wrong for integrated pipeline. Bypassing the error with:  does work but the code is not executed as the authenticated user but instead as the defaultAppPool and so the IIS user.

I know this is probably not the best question, I just can't wrap my head around impersonation with windows authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify user with LDAP/AD combination. This means user enters username and password from his own windows account and sends this data t server that can check if this data right. Of course this will work for Local networks with single LDAP server. 
Try following links for info: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18742/Simple-Active-Directory-Authentication-Using-LDAP
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the links, I was thinking about this but was hesitant since my web app is only small. However, I do think this will probably be the best solution long term.

Answer (score 1):

I would not want elevated rights in IIS. I would hand all data needed to do the job to another service that really does this work (as the right user).

Comment: The intranet website I have is just running some basic PowerShell scripts for our 1st line desk support. I would like to have it run the code as them so powershell is only getting access to what they have access to. If that makes sense, I just can't get impersonation to work and I don't understand why.